# Click Label if checkbox prop check is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, siblings

All check boxes by default are unchecked. I cannot use radio buttons in the problem.

When a checkbox is changed to `'checked'` then look to see if any of the sibling checkboxes are `'checked'`, if it is then `.click()` the parent `<label>` of the checkbox.

I have to `.click()` the `<label>` because the connected API is listening for a click on the label, `$('input').prop("checked", false);` doesn't seem to work.

Here is the structure:

```
<div class="feature-filter">
  <div id="filterHandle">Product Filter</div>
  <label class="featureLabel">
    <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox">
    Original Pouch
  </label>
  <label class="featureLabel">
    <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox">
    Original Can
  </label>
  <label class="featureLabel">
    <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox">
    Gold Pouch
  </label>
  <label class="featureLabel">
    <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox">
    Gold Can
  </label>
  <label class="featureLabel">
    <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox">
    Menthol Pouch
  </label>
  <label class="featureLabel">
    <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox">
    Menthol Can
  </label>
</div>
```

This is what i tried but it's wrong.

```
       $('.featureCheck').click(function(){

            if $('.featureCheck').siblings().prop('checked',true){
                this.find('label').click();
            }

        });
```

Comment: This line confuses me: *"When a checkbox is changed to 'checked' then look to see if any of the sibling checkboxes are 'checked', if it is then .click() the parent <label> of the checkbox."* - which checkbox?

Comment: If only one checkbox may be checked, you should be using radio boxes instead.

Comment: billyonecan click the parent label of the checkbox that is checked, but not the label of the checkbox that was just clicked. Arjan I tried radio buttons but the third party API is looking for checkboxes within labels, so radio doesn't work.

Comment: Your `if` statement is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
$('.featureCheck').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.featureCheck').not(this).filter(':checked').closest('.featureLabel').click();
  }
});
```

So if you check a checkbox, find others which are checked, and trigger the click event on their parent `label`

Answer (score 0):

Since the label is parent element of input checkbox, you should use `closest` or `parent` method. `find` is used to search children elements.

```
$(this).closest('.featureLabel').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/175/

```
<div class="feature-filter">
    <div id="filterHandle">Product Filter</div>
    <div class="item">
        <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="featureLabel">
            Original Pouch
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">        
        <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="featureLabel">
            Original Can
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">        
        <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="featureLabel">
            Gold Pouch
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="featureLabel">
            Gold Can
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="featureLabel">
            Menthol Pouch
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input class="featureCheck" type="checkbox"/>
        <label class="featureLabel">
            Menthol Can
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.featureCheck').on('click', function() {
        console.log($('.featureCheck:checked').length);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) { //if checkbox is checked and more than 1 are checked
            if($('.featureCheck:checked').length > 1) {
                $(this).closest('.item').find('.featureLabel').click();
            }
        }
    });
    $('.featureLabel').on('click', function() {
        alert('the feature label: ' + $(this).text() + ' was clicked.');
    });
});
```